# JFrame freeze with different System.in

Tags: java, swing, jframe, swingworker

Anyone can tell me why `TryGraphic` freeze the `JFrame` with a scanner in the first `main()`? If I remove the `Scanner` or if I execute the code directly, all works. (The original "Try" class obviously do a lot of different stuff. I wrote these classes to make it simple.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Try {

    public Try(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("FOO");
        String s = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

This is the graphic implementation:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;


public class TryGraphic extends JFrame{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7491282237007954227L;



    private JButton execute = new JButton("Esegui");

    private PipedInputStream inPipe = new PipedInputStream(); 
    private PipedInputStream outPipe = new PipedInputStream(); 
    private JTextField tfIn = new JTextField();
    private JTextArea outputArea = new JTextArea();

    private PrintWriter inWriter;


    public TryGraphic(){
        super("TRY");

        System.setIn(inPipe); 

        try {
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(new PipedOutputStream(outPipe), true)); 
            inWriter = new PrintWriter(new PipedOutputStream(inPipe), true); 
        }catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }               

        tfIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    String text = tfIn.getText();
                    tfIn.setText("");
                    inWriter.println(text); 
            }
        });

        this.add(execute,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.add(new JScrollPane(outputArea),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(tfIn, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        execute.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                SwingWorker<Void,String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() { 
                     protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception { 
                        Scanner s = new Scanner(outPipe);
                        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                                 String line = s.nextLine();
                                 publish(line);

                        }
                        return null; 
                    } 

                     @Override 
                     protected void process(java.util.List<String> chunks) { 
                         for (String line : chunks){ 
                             outputArea.append(line+System.lineSeparator());
                             outputArea.validate();
                             } 

                     } 
                };

                worker.execute();

                Try.main(new String[]{""});
            }

        });

        this.setSize(300,300);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }



    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TryGraphic();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're blocking the GUI Event Dispatch Thread. You need to spawn a separate thread to wait for input so you can keep your GUI responsive.

You're already doing the right thing by creating a `SwingWorker` to handle I/O in your `TryGraphic` class. You should do something similar to move the `Try.main(new String[]{""});` call off the Event Dispatch Thread, which will keep your JFrame from locking up.

Comment: I knew that the EDT was blocking, but I don't know how I can move `Try.main(String[] args)` out of the `actionPerformed`. Do I need to create separate thread for every function?

Comment: @Stereo89 - You need to move any potentially blocking computations off the EDT. Why are you blocking on reading `System.in` in a GUI application anyway? If you got the input through the GUI you could avoid this altogether.

Comment: I need to extend an exisisting class that already do "stuff", like ask for `String name` so I can't move the request in the GUI. I need to ask input when the `main()` asks for it. But you can help me with the meaning of "to move"? I need to create a `new Thread()`, a `new SwingWorker()`? The strange thing is that if I execute the code directly without a `JButton` that start the execution, everything works fine. I know the problem is the `actionPerformed`(`JButton execute`) because it needs of another `actionPerformed` (`JTextField tfIn`), but I don't know how resolve.

Comment: @Stereo89 - Yes, you should create a new `Thread`. You should make your `Try.main(new String[]{""})` call on that new thread so that it doesn't block the EDT. This works when you run it "without the button" because you call `Try.main` from the _main thread_ instead of the EDT. It blocks the _main thread_, but since that's separate from the EDT it doesn't cause your GUI to lock up.

Comment: So, if I move every instruction of the `actionPerformed` in a `Runnable`, do you think that everything works? I will try it and I will let you know. Thank you!